# How to filter only specific elements by Java 8 Predicate?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have collection `List<Foo>` of `Foo` elements:

```
class Foo {
  private TypeEnum type;
  private int amount;

  //getters, setters ...
}
```

`Foo` type can be `TypeEnum.A` and `TypeEnum.B`.

I would like to get only those `Foo` elements from list which if the element have `type == TypeEnum.B` then `amount` is greater than zero (`amount > 0`).

How can I do it by Java 8 Streams `filter()` method?

If I use:

```
List<Foo> l = list.stream()
    .filter(i -> i.getType().equals(TypeEnum.B) && i.getAmount() > 0)
    .collect(Collectors.<Foo>toList());
```

I get `Foo` elements with `TypeEnum.B` but without `TypeEnum.A`.

Comment: Wait do you want both `TypeEnum.A` and `TypeEnum.B` or just one? YOu mention both variants.

Comment: @xander yes, I want to get both value, but one of them filtered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
List<Foo> l = list.stream()
        .filter(i -> i.getType().equals(TypeEnum.B) ? i.getAmount() > 0 : true)
        .collect(Collectors.<Foo>toList());
```

It checks if `i.getAmount() > 0` only if `type` is equal to `TypeEnum.B`.

In your previous attempt your predicate was `true` only if `type` was `TypeEnum.B` and `amount` was greater than 0 - that's why you got only `TypeEnum.B` in return.

EDIT: you can also check a suggestion made by [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) (share some credits with him) in the comments section and use even shorter version of the expression:

```
!i.getType().equals(TypeEnum.B) || i.getAmount()>0
```

Comment: `!i.getType().equals(TypeEnum.B)  ||  i.getAmount()>0`

Comment: @Holger Good suggestion, adding a reference to it as well.